# Managed checkbox is disabled

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, package, developer-edition

I am trying to create a new managed package from my dev org. I am following the steps in the documentation - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_uploading.htm
. In the doc I see I have to go to setup->Package->Create new package. I am unable to select the managed checkbox option which is disabled. How can I enable it? I do not have any other package available nor I have created a namespace. This is a fresh developer org where I moved the code from another env.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need a namespace for a managed package.

The "Managed Packages in More Detail" section of [this help](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging) guide has more details on what is required.

Comment: Doesn't the doc say to create a managed package first? and then use namespaces etc

Comment: It's phrased poorly. You need a namespace first and then you create your package.

Comment: +1 John, you beat it to me. Unfortunately while typing from mobile it doesn't notify about an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register for a namespace as mentioned in document itself that its a prerequisite.

> Before creating a managed package:
>
> [Configure your developer settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/configure_developer_settings.htm#configure_developer_settings)

Comment: Are you saying the managed checkbox will be enabled only after I register the namespace? Do I need start creating the package meaning adding the components only after namespace is saved ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct!